# PHP: Cookies for Logging In

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication

Set cookie: (login)

```
    $settingCookie = $userDetail["salt"] . $userDetail["username"];

    setcookie("testing", $settingCookie, time()+43200); // 12 Hours
```

Check if logged in:

```
$loginCheck = $_COOKIE["testing"];
if (isset($loginCheck)) {
    // Logged in
} else {
    // Not logged in
}
```

I've sifted through a bunch of SO questions on this, but I'm still very unclear as to how to properly check if a cookie exists.

Obviously this is very insecure since you can just create a cookie `"testing"` within the browser, but I'm trying to fix that.

So how can I properly check if `$_COOKIE["testing"]` matches the salt and username that the user logged in with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward answer to your question is

```
if($_COOKIE["testing"] == $userDetail["salt"].$userDetail["username"]) {
```

But this is likely an ill-advised scheme, since I'm suspecting you don't know the specific username of the user on the page where you're checking for login.

So instead, you should assign two cookies, one for the username, and one for your secret token (which you're calling a salt—by the way, a salt is typically used in hashing, and you probably don't want to use it here). Then, once you have the username, look for a corresponding entry in the database with that username and the secret token. If one is found, then the user is logged in; if not, then the cookies are invalid.

This stops people from just randomly creating a cookie because they don't know the correct value of the token for other accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like that you are exposing the username. Create a hash function like:

```
md5(md5(sha($userDetail["salt"].$userDetail["username"])));
```

To use for your cookie.

You would have to store the details somewhere on the server (MySql, Memcache, etc) and compare the cookie from the client with what you have on the server.

Another option is to use PHP sessions for your logins.

Comment: Applying the hashing function several times does NOT improve its cryptographic qualities.